# What is needed to develop a macro or documentclass (.sty or .cls)

Tags: macros, document-classes

Sometimes I would like to design my own document classes or macros to meet personal requirements better. What knowledge is required?

I feel that developing these things are not really based on the usual latex commands we normally use. I’ve seen examples of self created document classes and there’re a lot of unfamiliar commands like ~ or @.

Comment: Too ambiguous requirement. Start with [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1), but you don't **need** to do complicated programming in these things, you can just put "simple" commands there as well like some `\newcommand` lines.

Comment: Then do this [packages - Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te?noredirect=1&lq=1).